# Use pyHook or msvcrt in windows service (python)

Tags: python, service, msvcrt, keylogger, pyhook

I am trying to make a simple keylogger with pyHook or msvcrt.

Both modules work fine when I compile the code and run the .exe file.

But when I'm trying to run the .exe as a windows service (using NSSM if that's matter), the service does not seem to log the pressed keys.

I know the service is working, because it is writing to the files, communicating with sockets etc.

The problem is only with the keylogger.

I suspect the problem is that the service runs in it's own environment so it doesn't recognize the key presses.

Any suggestions how to bypass it?

Here is the keylogger:

```
    while True:
        c = msvcrt.getch()
        if ord(c) == 8:
            buffer = buffer[:-1]
        else:
            buffer += c

        # write the buffer to file
```

Thanks in advance.